# Deduping dataset based on missing dates

Tags: sql, database, sas

I have a dataset which has two date fields , one is dispute_date and the other is credit_date, I have to dedup this dataset on acct_num based on these criteria :

1. If dispute_date is blank for some record and non blank for other , keep the non blank record.
2. If dispute_date is non blank for all the records , keep the record with earliest dispute_date.
3. If dispute_date is  blank for all the records , keep the record with earliest credit_date.

Here is my sample dataset :

```
 input acct_num  dispute_date credit_date ;
    DATALINES; 
    55203610   .         23FEB2020
    55203610   .         13MAR2020
    55203610   31DEC2019 17MAR2020
    55203612   22FEB2021 09JUN2021  
    55203612   .         31DEC2021
    55203614   .         21SEP2018
    55203614   .         23JUL2018
    55203615   22FEB2018 21SEP2018
    55203615   01FEB2018 23JUL2018
    ;
    run;
```

Data I want

```
     input acct_num  dispute_date credit_date ;
    DATALINES; 
    
    55203610   31DEC2019 17MAR2020
    55203612   22FEB2021 09JUN2021  
    55203614   .         23JUL2018
    55203615   01FEB2018 23JUL2018
    ;
    run;
```

I have used proc sort but its not giving me correct results . Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary sort variable e.g.

```
if missing(dispute_date) then sort_dispute_date = 999999;
else sort_dispute_date = dispute_date;
```

Then sort by sort_dispute_date and credit_date and the first record will be what you want.

Comment: Sorry but what should be in the place of 999999

Comment: 99999 is just a dummy value we are assigning to missing values so that when you sort by that, any missing values will end up last.  So here you create the temporary sort variable that is the same except missing will get sorted last. Then you sort the entire data set by that modified dispute date as the primary and credit date as the secondary.  Now you can see that the first record will be the smallest known dispute date value, and if there happen to be multiple records with the same dispute date (or if all are missing) then the first record will be the smallest credit date, as desired.

Comment: You can drop sort_dispute_date after sorting, it's only a temporary variable.